# Display photos from database as Author Profile for Library Table

Tags: php, html, css

Recently I learned about PHP and Database, I wrote the script below to display the image as a Profile for Author, but the photo doesn't show up! , Here my script :

```
echo "<tr class=\"alert\" role=\"alert\">
        <td class=\"center\">$data[id_pengarang]</td>
        <td class=\"d-flex align-items-center\">
            <div class=\"img\">
                <img src=\"img_pengarang/$data[foto]\" alt=\"$data[id_pengarang]\"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>$data[nama]</td>
        <td>$data[alamat]</td>
        <td>$data[email]</td>
        <td>$data[hp]</td>
        <td class=\"status\"><span class=\"active\">Active</span></td>
        <td><a href=\"nim-view.php id=$data[id_pengarang]\">Edit</a> &nbsp
        <a href=\"nim-del.php id=$data[id_pengarang]\">Hapus</a>
        </td>
    </tr>";
```

And when I'm inspect the image , any error in Console it say

user-1.png:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Can someone tell me how to correct this? I tried to change double quotes to single quotes, but still doesn't work at all.

Or Maybe there is an error in the database?

Thank you for the help

Comment: You should first of all go and check what the HTML code this generated, actually looks like.

Comment: Try inspect and check what is coming in background-image url ?

Comment: check table css

Comment: What does `$data[foto]` contain? Does the image exist?

Comment: `<td class="d-flex align-items-center">
   <div class="img" style="background-image: url(" user-1.png");"=""></div>
</td>`
here when I'm inspect in localhost `user-1.png` is photo from the database @HamzaZafeer

Comment: `style="background-image: url(" user-1.png")` - so the actual value you assigned to the style attribute here is just `background-image: url(` - after that comes a double quote, and that is the same delimiter you already used to _start_ the attribute value. Hint: URLs in `background:image: url(...)` do not have to be in quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `div` instead of `img` tag.

Try it, this will work:

```
echo "
<tr class=\"alert\" role=\"alert\">
  <td class=\"center\">$data[id_pengarang]</td>
  <td class=\"d-flex align-items-center\">
    <div class=\"img\">
      <img src="$data['foto']" alt="" />
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>$data[nama]</td>
  <td>$data[alamat]</td>
  <td>$data[email]</td>
  <td>$data[hp]</td>
  <td class=\"status\"><span class=\"active\">Active</span></td>
  <td><a href="nim-view.php id=$data[id_pengarang]\">Edit</a> &nbsp
    <a href=\"nim-del.php id=$data[id_pengarang]\">Hapus</a>
  </td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: I've tried it, it was completely empty at first, but now image does not load with alt attribute

Comment: You can try again like this:                                                                                                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(' . $data['foto'] . ');"></div>

Comment: still not working, but I'm still trying the initial script that you gave, when I'm inspect the image ,I open the console and it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status user-1.png:1 of 404 (Not Found)` , maybe there is an error in the database?

Comment: yes please double check again your database

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on this:

The image should be present at the exact path given in CSS Property: `background-color`.

Also, please test if the image is working by trying to place image tag and path with:

`<img src=[GENERATED PATH]/>`

The cleaned up code should be like this:

```
echo '<tr class="alert" role="alert">
        <td class="center">' . $data['id_pengarang'] . '</td>
        <td class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(' . $data['foto'] . ');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>' . $data['nama'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $data['alamat'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $data['email'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $data['hp'] . '</td>
        <td class="status"><span class="active">Active</span></td>
        <td><a href="nim-view.php?id=' . $data['id_pengarang'] .'">Edit</a> &nbsp
        <a href="nim-del.php?id=' . $data['id_pengarang'] .'">Hapus</a>
        </td>
    </tr>';
```